# rename_if() together with starts_with() to prefix certain columns

Tags: r, dplyr, rename, tidyverse, purrr

My data looks like this:

```
#>           Artist          Album Year
#> 1        Beatles  Sgt. Pepper's 1967
#> 2 Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers 1971
```

And my question should be quite simple. I'm trying to use `rename_if` to prefix only the columns that start with the letter "A". So my desired output is:

```
#>       df1_Artist      df1_Album Year
#> 1        Beatles  Sgt. Pepper's 1967
#> 2 Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers 1971
```

You can see that "Year" should not be prefixed.

This is my attempt, but it's not quite working. Am I using `starts_with` incorrectly? Should I try break it into two lines so I can understand it more clearly? The purrr style functions I'm still learning, so it's not always intuitive to me yet.

```
df1 %>% rename_if(starts_with("A"), .funs = ~ paste0(df1, .))
#> Error in df1 %>% rename_if(starts_with("A"), .funs = ~paste0(df1, .)): could not find function "%>%"
```

Code for data input:

```
df1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
      Artist = c("Beatles", "Rolling Stones"),
       Album = c("Sgt. Pepper's", "Sticky Fingers"),
        Year = c(1967, 1971)
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`rename_if` expects a logical vector as predicate function. `starts_with` selects variables based on their name. Use base `startsWith` instead which returns a logical vector based on prefix

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% rename_if(startsWith(names(.), "A"), ~paste0("df1_", .))

#      df1_Artist      df1_Album Year
#1        Beatles  Sgt. Pepper's 1967
#2 Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers 1971
```

Or if you want to stay in `tidyverse` you can also use `str_detect`

```
df1 %>% rename_if(stringr::str_detect(names(.), "^A"), ~paste0("df1_", .))
```

---

To use `starts_with` we can use `rename_at` which has `vars` argument.

```
df1 %>% rename_at(vars(starts_with("A")), ~paste0("df1_", .))
```

Comment: This edit is very helpful in explaining the difference between `rename_at` and `rename_if` to me. I'd never understood the difference before. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, do you recommend any particular source for me to learn things like `rename_at` and `rename_if` and purrr functions? Would Hadley's R4DS be the best thing for me to work through?

Comment: @RAndStata Unfortunately, I'll not be the best person to answer that because I haven't read much of the resources online. My knowledge mostly comes from reading other people's answers here and checking documentation of functions while trying to answer questions.

Answer (score 4):

We can use

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  rename_at(vars(starts_with("A")), ~ str_c("df1_", .))
#     df1_Artist      df1_Album Year
#1        Beatles  Sgt. Pepper's 1967
#2 Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers 1971
```